# How to wipe RAID superblock? wipefs: error: /dev/sda: probing initialization failed

Tags: partitioning, raid

I want to format my external USB.
lsblk shows

```
sda           8:0    1  57.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    1   2.9G  0 part /media/miki/Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS amd64
├─sda2        8:2    1   3.9M  0 part 
└─sda3        8:3    1  54.8G  0 part /media/miki/writable
```

I tried standard procedures

```
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda
mdadm: Couldn't open /dev/sda for write - not zeroing
```

And wipefs

```
sudo wipefs -a /dev/sda
wipefs: error: /dev/sda: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy
```

What should I try now? What is the root cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the raid first:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/mdXX
```

See `cat /proc/mdstat` to see which device is in a software raid.